# inDesign Scripting - Cut from "typesetting script" TextFrame and paste on empty TextFrame

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I need an Adobe Script that do this:

- Select TextFrame with the whole Text Script (page1, text, page2, text and so on);
- Cut a paragraph (usually separated by a **\r** or **^p**);
- User selects or create a new TextFrame;
- Paste the line cut before on the new empty TextFrame; and
- Go to the next paragraph.

I've been doing this typesetting job and I came across this [Typesetterer](https://illuminati-manga.com/illiteracy/typesetterer/) for Photoshop, went on a journey to find a similar script/application for inDesign and I found this [this solution](https://github.com/RisingFog/InDesign-Scripts), tried it and worked, boosting my productivity by at least 2x. Tried this [split one](http://eugenyus.rudtp.ru/en/splitTextByPars) but it takes way longer to resize and move all the generated TextFrames. But it was really useful in developing my final code.

The main problem with this approach is that it required the typesetting script to be in a .txt file, which breaks all **Bold** and *Italic* from the original script.

```js
main();

function main() { // Main() just to keep it organized
  try {
    var myMeasuringUnit = app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit;
    app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = MeasurementUnits.POINTS;
  } catch (exception) {
    alert(exception.description);
    exit();
  }

  var myTextFrameSelection = app.activeDocument.selection;
  cutAndPaste(myTextFrameSelection);

  try {
    app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = myMeasuringUnit;
  } catch (exception) {}
}

function cutAndPaste(myTextFrameSelection) {
  for (elementsInSelection = 0; elementsInSelection < myTextFrameSelection.length; elementsInSelection++) {
    if (myTextFrameSelection[elementsInSelection].constructor.name == "TextFrame") {
      var myParagraphs = myTextFrameSelection[elementsInSelection].texts[0].paragraphs;
      var isCopied = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < myParagraphs.length; i++) {
        try {
          myParagraphs[i].insertionPoints.itemByRange(0, -2).select();
          app.cut();
          isCopied = true;
        } catch (exception) {
          isCopied = false;
        }
        if (isCopied) {
          /*
          Attempt at adding a way to select another TextFrame and app.paste() the previously app.cut() line in it

          var doc = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
          doc.addEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);

          function selectionChanged() {
              if (doc.selection[0] instanceof TextFrame && doc.selection[0].contents == '' && doc.selection[1] == null) {
                  if (doc.selection[0] instanceof TextFrame) {
                  doc.selection[0].contents = app.paste();
              }
          }
          */
          app.paste(); // This just pastes it in the same folder
        }
      }
    }
  }
} // For now, what it does it "cut paragraph from the TextFrame but also paste in the same TextFrame"
```

So far, it just cut from the TextFrame, paragraph after paragraph, and it pastes on the same TextFrame. It's close to doing what I need, but I can't seem to find a way to select a new Frame while in the main loop. I commented out the possible solution that I'm struggling to get to work.

Maybe I'm using the wrong cut/paste functions too? Maybe it is easier to modify the 2nd link solution to accept .docx?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, it can be done via script. But, wait... It could be done way easier (for a normal person, not a coder) without scripts at all. If you have the empty frames and some text, you can just link the empty text frames and paste the script-text into the first frame of this chain. And there is the special symbol (and style properties, if you wish) to make a next paragraph start in next frame.

Comment: For coders, I'd suggest to add the basic markdown-like formatting (just Bold and Italic, nothing fancy) into the txt-srcipt-file and add the function to the second RisingFos's script that will parse this formatting into actual Bolds and Italics as the text is pasting into a selected frame. Moreover, if you don't mind the markdown/html formatting in txt-script-file it can be just another simply script that will loop through all your text frames and makes Bolds/Italics.

Comment: Also there's no such thing as 'Adobe Typescript'

Comment: @YuriKhristich The problem with the .txt solution is that I lose not only bold/italics, but also font colors, sizes and styles. And I'm not the one who makes the script-text and it's also not a single person, so it would be hard to make a lot of tags for different types of script-text makers. It is indeed a good sugestion, but it would take a good time to learn all the small details from each person making it. The solution presented in my code is the one I'm looking for, but the problem is mixing the RisingFrog's "select empty frame and paste contents"...

Comment: What about linked text frames? If you already have the empty frames you can click on first one, hold Alt and do several clicks on next frames. It will be about the same amount of clicks and moves as with a script. And there is built-in script (SplitStory.jsx) to break links between selected frames if you want unlinked frames after all.

Comment: I don't understand the linked text frame concept, do you have an example so I can get to understand it? Tried to use it on my file and couldn't get it to work as you said.

Comment: Oh I got it to work, but it doesn't split by paragraph, it fills the textbox entirelly with multiple paragraphs

Comment: If each of your text frames contains only one paragraph, it makes sense to apply to paragraphs a style that will start every paragraph in next frame. https://imgur.com/FPSqWi1

Comment: Now it worked and it's an awesome approach I've never heard of, thank you for this too!

Comment: Maybe this would work if I knew what the next frame content would be before pasting, because in the text-script it has like "page1" that also get pasted in the next linked frame.

Comment: I have no idea how the Text Script looks like, so it hard to guess what you could do. Especially given that you didn't use linked text frames in InDesing until today. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important difference between [RisingFog's solution](https://github.com/RisingFog/InDesign-Scripts) and [Eugeny Budantsev solition](http://eugenyus.rudtp.ru/en/splitTextByPars) is the interaction with user. Former script shows the dialog window and keep it running until you close the window. Later runs just once and can't keep tracking user manipulations.

So if you want to keep your script running (and doing something as reaction on user manipulations) you need to show a some window even if the window will be empty. Something like this:

```
#targetengine session

var dialog = new Window("palette", undefined, undefined);
    dialog.preferredSize.width = 200;
    dialog.preferredSize.height = 50;
    dialog.text = "Select next frame";
    dialog.onClose = function() {
        doc.removeEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);
    }

dialog.show();

var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.addEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);

function selectionChanged() {

    // here is the code that will run wenever you change selection

    if (doc.selection[0] instanceof TextFrame
        && doc.selection[0].contents == ''
        && doc.selection[1] == null) {
        alert('Next empty text frame is selected!')
    }
}
```

Of course you can fill the window with some texts or buttons.

**Update**

Here is the example how you can cut first paragraph from selected non-empty text frame (suppose it's the Text Script) and paste this paragraph automatically into next selected empty frame:

```
#targetengine session

var dialog = new Window("palette", undefined, undefined);
    dialog.preferredSize.width = 300;
    dialog.preferredSize.height = 50;
    dialog.text = "Please, select next frame";
    dialog.onClose = function() {
        doc.removeEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);
    }

    dialog.add("statictext", undefined, "Last cutted text:");

var msg = dialog.add("edittext");
    msg.text = "";
    msg.characters = 40

dialog.show();

var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.addEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);

function selectionChanged() {

    var sel = doc.selection[0];

    if (sel instanceof InsertionPoint) sel = sel.parent.textContainers[0];

    if (sel instanceof TextFrame || sel instanceof Story) {

        if (sel.contents != '') {
            app.select(sel.paragraphs[0], SelectionOptions.REPLACE_WITH);
            msg.text = sel.paragraphs[0].contents;
            app.cut();
            app.selection = null;
        }
        else {
            sel.texts.everyItem().select();
            app.paste();
            app.selection = null;

            // remove '\r' at the very end of text in the frame
            app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat ="\r$";
            app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "";
            sel.changeGrep();

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

Here is the same script. Only difference, you don't need click on Text Script frame anymore. You need select the text frame before you run the script and then the script will cut first paragraph from this frame automatically every time when you click on any empty text frame.

```
#targetengine session

var dialog = new Window("palette", undefined, undefined);
dialog.preferredSize.width = 300;
dialog.preferredSize.height = 50;
dialog.text = "Please, select next frame";
dialog.onClose = function() {doc.removeEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged)}

dialog.add("statictext", undefined, "Last copied text:");

var msg = dialog.add("edittext");
msg.text = "";
msg.characters = 40;

// --- here is the Pause button
var pause = false;
var pause_btn = dialog.add("button", [10,10,300,30], "Pause");
pause_btn.onClick = function() {
    pause = !pause;
    // if (pause) msg.text = "[PAUSED] " + msg.text; // it can be done better, but it works, too
    // if (!pause) msg.text = msg.text.replace(/^\[PAUSED\] /, "");
    pause_btn.text = pause ? "Resume" : "Pause"; // this is way better
};
// ---

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var master_frame = app.selection[0]; // <-- the Text Script frame

if (master_frame instanceof TextFrame || master_frame instanceof Story) {
    dialog.show();
    app.selection = null;
    doc.addEventListener('afterSelectionChanged', selectionChanged);
} else {
    alert("Please, select a frame with text before run the script!");
    exit();
}

function selectionChanged() {

    if (pause) return; // <-- here you check the state of the button

    var sel = doc.selection[0];

    if (sel instanceof InsertionPoint) sel = sel.parent.textContainers[0];
    if (sel instanceof TextFrame || sel instanceof Story) {

        if (sel.contents == '' && master_frame.contents != '') {

            app.select(master_frame.paragraphs[0], SelectionOptions.REPLACE_WITH);
            msg.text = master_frame.paragraphs[0].contents;
            app.cut();
            app.selection = null;
            sel.texts.everyItem().select();
            app.paste();
            app.selection = null;

            // remove '\r' at the end
            app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat ="\r$";
            app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "";
            sel.changeGrep();

        }

        if (master_frame.contents == '') alert ("No text to paste anymore!")
    }
}
```

I've added 'Pause' button to the window.

Comment: That will help a lot to try my 1st approach to the problem. So I needed the window open to keep the code going, my mistake, now I need a way to populate a list variable with all paragraphs and whenever I select an empty frame, paste the contents of var on the [i] position.

Comment: A problem I found is: how do I store a app.cut() value to a variable?

Comment: Alas, there is no way to put a content of clipboard directly into variable. You can do `app.cut()` then `app.paste()`. For some objects it makes sense: `var variable = app.selection` after or before cut/copy/paste. Just pasted objects are selected, usually.

Comment: I've added the example to my answer. It pastes into empty frames just fine. Basically the workflow as follows: click on big frame with Text Script, click on empty frame, and again: click on the Text Script and then click on empty frame.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it's brilliant and it works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Looks funny, but, to be honest, I see no enormous advantage over the simply common classic Click-Click-Click,Ctrl+X, Click,Ctrl+V. Unless it's should be done hundreds times, with a stopwatch or something like that. And on Windows with Autohotkey you can make mouse to perform click-click-click-ctrl-c with Wheel and ctrl+v with Ctrl+Wheel. https://i.imgur.com/sO4PfI4.png Etc.

Comment: Yeah, in it's current state is just a similar way to the normal routine, but if we are able to make so it works as RisingFrog's, where you just click the empty TF, would save a lot of time. (Maybe make a boolean to click the text-script and then turn it to true/false to keep going back to it after every SelectionChanged). Also I've been using the AHK in a script I made myself to copy and paste using the same button, in turns :) and one problem with AHK is that there's no AHK in Mac (for my dear father that is my boss haha)

Comment: I didn't try to use RisingFog's script, I don't know exactly how it works. I think I can make the script to cut next paragraph automatically from the first text frame when you select next empty text frame. I see no problem there except maybe user's vertigo.

Comment: I've made the next version of the script, see my second update. As for to copy/paste between files... Probably it could be done. I can't tell it right now. It's need to try.

Comment: I've added 'Pause' button to the window.